# Did a cheetah refuse to race against dogs?

Tags: zoology, sport

[image: dogs running a track while a cheetah sits in a racing stall]

> This speed race wanted to know the fastest, the dogs or the cheetah. But the cheetah did not move a finger and sat in place. People asked the race coordinator what happened. He responded after seeing him saying:
>
> "Sometimes trying to prove that you are the best is an insult!"

Is this a photograph of a race where a cheetah refused to race against dogs?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: While trying to find an example of the claim, the answer became obvious, so I just posted it rather than pretending I didn't see it and looking for someone making the claim.

Comment: Welcome to HNQ visitors. Please see [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130508/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-did-a-cheetah-refuse-to-race-against-dogs) associated with this question. Please only use comments to improve the question. Answers should go in an answer box. We do not care about your personal opinions on this claim.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No.

[Snopes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/cheetah-greyhound-audi-ad/) explains it is from an advert from Audi:

> [image: Audi advert]

Snopes references a broken link for its source. Here is [an equivalent](https://adsspot.me/media/prints/audi-s4-quattro-cheetah-702b179bc691). It names the photographer, [Simon Mooney](https://www.mooneyphoto.com/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130508/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-did-a-cheetah-refuse-to-race-against-dogs).

Comment: This says nothing about whether the photo was made for the ad or just used in it.

Comment: @Haukinger The answer says, "*it is from an advert from Audi.*" The supporting Snopes article elaborates, *"[a]ccording to online advertising archive Coloribus the photograph was created by the BBH London advertising agency in 2000 and carried the slogan 'nothing to prove.'*" It seems the photograph was created for this ad.

Comment: Snopes just quotes another site, that doesn't give it any credibility, and even if it did, "created by [...] advertising agency" does not mean that it wasn't taken at an actual race.

Comment: @Haukinger: What would it take to convince you that the far most plausible option is the perfectly prosaic description of an advert made by the explicitly listed photographer, artistic director and creative director, and not a secretly plagiarised photograph of a surreal and meaningless situation that no-one can find documentation about?

Comment: @Oddthinking to be sure, one would need an affidavit from the photographer

Comment: @Haukinger: Ok. Go get it and post an answer. (I gave a link to his web-site.) This question is so low value and importance, I don't think it warrants bothering anyone about.

Comment: I've deleted a lot of comments contain people's unsubstantiated personal opinions (the antithesis of this site) and other comments not about improving the answer. See the link above for the chat room.